# Missing encryption

Tags: 5.1-lollipop, disk-encryption

I have recently bought an Android smartphone ([Doogee X5](http://www.doogeemobile.com/doogee-x5.html)) with Android 5.1. But I'm having difficulty locating [full disk encryption](https://source.android.com/security/encryption/index.html) option. There is nothing in security and storage menus. The closest thing I saw was "data protection" for files which is clearly not a full disk encryption.

PS: I tried adding screen lock (PIN) as suggested in guides, but I see no change.

Comment: Can you create a guest or a secondary user in your device? I suppose no given the hardware constraint. It may be possible that your OEM dropped support for encryption for the same reason. [Section 9, sub-section 9.9](https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/source.android.com/en//compatibility/android-cdd.pdf) - though I'm still looking for some hard and convincing fact for my speculation to be true.

Comment: I have the exact same problem with the siswoo c55 longbow

Answer (score 0):

Full disk encryption is mandatory for all devices shipping with Android 6.0 Marshmallow. Since your device is shipping with 5.1 it probably doesn't have it implemented or does not meet the minimum requirements to support it.

Note that even if you upgrade to 6.0 chances are that you still won't be getting it since its only mandatory for devices that ship with 6.0 out of the box, upgraded devices are not required to have it (for ex. Nexus 5 has Marshmallow but has no encryption because the hardware does not support it).

So, it just isn't implemented by the OEM.